# Newtosoft Json library deserialization RuntimeBinderException in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, json.net

I'm importing a C# project to Unity. Newtonsoft json library works well in a C# project (as a Nugget package), but it throws an exception in Unity (as an asset store package). I'm using newest packages and the following syntax:

```
dynamic myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString)
dynamic myObj2 = myObj.myObj2 ;
```

Newtonsoft library in Unity throws an exception (on line 2):

```
RuntimeBinderException: 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'myObj2 '
```

My data format (simplified):

```
{
"myObj2": [
    {
        "name": "name1",
        "parameters": [
            {
                "paramName" : "parameter1",
                "type": "Bool",
                "value": "false"
            },
            {
                "paramName" : "parameter2",
                "type": "GameObject",
                "value": "someGameObjectName"
            }               
            ]
    }
]
}
```

What would be a good way to bypass this issue?

Comment: Well, does your json string represent a json object, and does this json object have a key named "myObj2" (case-sensitive!) ? If yes, try `var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString); var y = x["myObj2"];`. Not sure about the root cause, but it could be worth trying to avoid `dynamic` here.

Comment: Could you provide your json data?

Comment: Don't you normally need to do JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectType>(jsonString);

Comment: I will add the data, var and specifying the type didn't work well too for some reason...

Comment: What do you get if you use the `var` approach instead of `dynamic`?

Comment: With the ObjectType and the var I get the following: To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Comment: Is your method call really just `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, or is it in reality the generic variant `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<something>`?

Comment: Note also, that we only know about the two code lines in your question. If you tell us some error, make sure to precisely note which line of your code causes this error/exception. Otherwise, we might become wrong-footed, giving wrong advice and you are stuck with your problem...

Comment: They are written exactly like this and work well but not in Unity. The error is encountered on line 2

Comment: You mean, when using the `var` approach, the error happens on the line with `myObj["myObj2"];`?

Comment: for var syntax alone I get the following error
"Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'" on line 2

Comment: What is the real type of the myObj? Do something like this: `myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString); var typeName = myObj.GetType().FullName;` What is the *typeName*?

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject

Comment: Stupid me. Sorry, i had blinders on for a while. The return type of JsonConvert.DeserializeObject is of course object. Doh!. Do the second line like `((JObject) myObj)["myObj2"];`. Sorry for being so daft the whole time ;)

Comment: Or better, leave the 2nd line as is, and change the 1st line to `var myObj = (JObject) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);`

Comment: @Julia try my answer and let me know if its work for you

Comment: YES! It works! :) Unity likes this syntax. elgonzo Thank you for the help! Thanks D-john for the elaborate answer as well (I would prefer to use dynamic in my case)

Comment: D-john Anshani the second case throws the exception

Comment: I have tested this both which exception you are getting @Julia

Answer (score 0):

Create Model And then DeserializeObject and access all the values

I am Reading Same your json From D://readjson.txt in my example

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string data = File.ReadAllText("D://readjson.txt");
            var datavales = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(data);

            foreach(var vales in datavales.myObj2)
            {
                //access values from here
                Console.WriteLine(vales.name);
            }
        }
    }
    public class Parameter
    {
        public string paramName { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyObj2
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<Parameter> parameters { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<MyObj2> myObj2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Another Approach maybe you need this:-**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string data = File.ReadAllText("D://readjson.txt");
            dynamic datavales = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);

            dynamic keydata = datavales.myObj2;
            foreach(dynamic obj2values in keydata)
            {
               //obj2values contain all the values access it using obj2values object
               Console.WriteLine( obj2values.name);
            }

        }
```